# How to wish "get well soon" in the 3rd person

Tags: expressions

How to I convey "get-well soon-wishes" to a mother for her child.

Is there a more idiomatic expression than "I wish your son to get well soon"?

I am looking for an expression that can be used in emails and is professional but not too formal.

Comment: "I hope you son gets well soon." or "I hope you son will soon be feeling better."

Comment: I am voting to migrate to our sister site ELL.stackexchange.com targeted at people learning English.

Comment: I don't like "I hope ..." because it might imply "...because then you can concentrate on our work again" in certain contexts.

Comment: No, hope doesn't imply that. It's just friendly. "Best wishes to your son, and I hope he soon feels better."

Comment: Another way to say it "Sorry to hear about your son. I hope he soon feels better."

Comment: Please do not ask for help writing (or proofreading). They are out of scope and your question may be removed. [(more)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)  Questions that invite many equally valid answers are out of scope. [(more)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)  These same considerations also apply to our sister site [ell.se].

Comment: You may use: `I wish your son a speedy recovery.`